# Overloaded Virtual Function in Virtual Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

My question is bit lengthy. Kindly answer it only once you go through the whole problem.

I have implemented the Diamond Problem as follows:

```
class Polygon
{

protected:
    int sides;

public:

    Polygon()
    {
        cout << "Polygon's Default Constructor being called." << endl;
    }

    Polygon(int a)
    {
        cout << "Polygon's parameterized Constructor being called." << endl;
        sides = a;
    }

    void virtual Draw()
    {
        cout << "Polygon being drawn." << endl;
    }

    virtual ~Polygon()
    {
        cout << "Polygon's Destructor being called." << endl;
    }

};


class Triangle : virtual public Polygon
{
    int Angles[3];
public:
    Triangle()
    {
        cout << "Triangle's Default Constructor being called." << endl;

    }

    Triangle(int a)
    {
        cout << "Triangle's parameterized Constructor being called." << endl;
        sides = a;
    }

    Triangle(int a, int b) : Polygon(a)
    {
        cout << "Triangle's double parameterized Constructor being called." << endl;
        //sides = a;
    }


    void virtual Draw()
    {
        cout << "Triangle being drawn." << endl;
    }

    ~Triangle()
    {
        cout << "Triangle's Destructor being called." << endl;
    }

};

class IsoscelesPolygon : virtual public Polygon
{
    void virtual Draw()
    {
        cout << "Isosceles Polygon's Draw Called." << endl;
    }
};

class IsoscelesTriangle : public Triangle, public IsoscelesPolygon
{

    void Draw(int )
    {
        cout << "Isoceles Triangle's Draw() Called." << endl;
    }
};
```

It works perfectly fine and resolves the Diamond Problem due to virtual inheritance. But when I change `Draw()` in `IsocelesTriangle` to `Draw(int)`, it starts giving me error like this:

[image: Overloaded Function (virtual in parent class) in Virtual Inheritance]

This error doesn't pop up and program successfully runs (in non-polymorphic way obviously) when I make the `Draw()` in `Polygon` as non-virtual. Why? What link does it (`virtual` function in base class) have to do with the signature of `Draw()` in `IsocelesTriangle`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the idea is that if you don't override `Draw` in `IsoscelesTriangle` (and changing the signature is not overriding anymore), you end up with 2 `Draw` functions in the final class `IsoscelesTriangle`, one from `IsoscelesPolygon` and other from `Triangle`, and both try to override the `Draw` from `Polygon`. The compiler finds it ambiguous. Note that g++ spits out a more readable error:

```
error: virtual function 'Polygon::Draw' has more than one final overrider in 'IsoscelesTriangle'
```

The virtual inheritance just ensures that the base object `Polygon` is not appearing twice in `IsoscelesTriangle`. In your case, whenever you explicitly override `Draw`, the compiler hides the other 2 `Draw`s coming from `Triangle` and `IsoscelesPolygon`, so no more confusion.

PS: you'll find the same error even if you remove `Draw` completely from `IsoscelesTriangle`. Good question anyway, hope I got it right.

---

Now, regarding the last part of your question

> > This error doesn't pop up and program successfully runs (in non-polymorphic way obviously) when I make the Draw() in Polygon as non-virtual

The idea here is that now each `Triangle` and `IoscelesPolygon` declare `Draw` as `virtual`, so basically they start with a clean state and overload the function `Draw` from `Polygon` (which was marked as non-virtual). You then end up with 2 **different** `Draw` functions in `IsoscelesTriangle`, which are not trying to **override** the `Draw` from `Polygon`.

Comment: you mean if `Draw()` is not virtual probably... still trying to figure this out

Comment: Yeah as I mentioned in question as well: when I convert Draw() of Polygon to non-virtual, error doesn't pop up and program executes without any trouble.

Comment: But even if I convert Draw() in Triangle and IsoscelesPolygon to non-virtual, still error appears. Only thing which changes it is Polygon's Draw()'s conversion to non-virtual.

Comment: even if you don't explicitly mark the intermediate functions as `virtual`, the function are still considered `virtual`. So if you have a base class with `virtual void Base::f()`, then `void Derived::f()` is **automatically** virtual, without having to specify explicitly the `virtual` keyword.

Comment: That is something new for me. Your answer is a good one but still I am bit skeptical to grasp the phenomenon I encountered

Comment: @TalhaIrfan have to say I'm not 100% confident in my answer and I'd like to see someone jumping in and criticizing it. But that's at least what I believe happens. The only part I am not 100% confident is the hiding of the 2 intermediate virtual functions when explicitly overriding the one in `IsoscelesTriangle`. If that statement is correct, then the answer is correct.