# What is the difference between polymorphism and overloading?

Tags: c++, haskell, computer-science

I understand polymorphism and vaguely understand overloading, but would appreciate someone that thoroughly understands there two concepts to explain what the categorical difference is and whether overloading is or is not a form of polymorphism (seems to be disagreement about this).

Comment: You could do worse than looking up on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29

Comment: Haskell has *parametric polymorphism*, where you have functions that work identically over multiple types, e.g. `length :: [a] -> Int` works for lists of Strings, lists of Doubles, etc.  All you need is a single definition, as a parametrically polymorphic value doesn't care about what the parameter is, just where it's used.

It also has typeclasses which it uses for *ad hoc polymorphism*, functions where the implementation is type dependant, e.g. `show :: Show a => a -> String` is a family of functions each with its own definition: `show :: Int -> String, show :: Double -> String, ...`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Polymorphism, at its core, is about multiple things which all have a certain set of consistent behavior, such that you can replace one with another within a particular algorithm or process. So long as they all provide the expected interface, the process still works.

Overloading doesn't really have such a foundation. It is merely the ability to name two or more functions with the same name, so long as they have different parameter lists. The compiler figure out which function you actually meant based on the types of the arguments you pass.

Now overloading can be used to create polymorphism. Consider the following:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T t) {call(t);}
```

This will call `call`, passing `t` as a parameter. This will work so long as you provide a type `T` for which `call(t)` is legitimate C++ code. You could do this by overloading the function `call` for whatever types you are interested in using with `func`:

```
void call(int);
void call(float);
void call(vector<int>);
```

In this way, `func` is a function which is polymorphic (statically) with respect to its parameter. It can perform its operation on any type, so long as that type has the appropriate interface. That interface being the ability to call a function `call` with a variable of that type.

```
func(5); //Legal
func(13.4); //Legal
func(vector<int>{4, 3, 2, 1}); //Legal
func(vector<float>{}); //NOT legal
```

Here, we use function overloading of `call` to create a form of polymophism through the `func` function. But this does not mean that overloading *is* polymorphism.

Overloading is a language tool. Polymorphism is a concept. Polymorphism is about making multiple objects all work the same way. Overloading is just a way to give different functions the same name.

Answer (score 4):

Polymorphism: one method which has multiple implementations depending on the type of the argument(s) with which it is invoked.  Often not known at compile time.  The number of arguments is fixed, and in C++ the only argument whose type matters is the first one (`this`).  In C++ the common version of this requires a base class with `virtual` methods.

Overloading: one name which is actually multiple methods depending on the count and type of the argument(s) with which it is invoked.  Always decided at compile time.  No base class is involved.

If you'd like an analogy: polymorphism is when you hire a dozen specialist mechanics to work on cars, and each one of them has functions like `do_work(vehicle)` and `take_vacation(duration)`.  Each one does something different but they all have the same signature apart from the "implicit this" argument in C++ (aka `self` in Python, etc.).  Overloading is when you hire generalist mechanics and each one of them has `do_work(steering)`, `do_work(lighting)`, `do_work(engine)`, etc.

Comment: Last paragraph is gold!!

Comment: What about "compile-time polymorphism"?

Comment: @NickyC: There are two kinds of compile-time polymorphism in C++: the kind that is an optimization because the compiler sees which implementation needs to be invoked, and the kind that is a language feature using template metaprogramming.  The first still relies on `virtual` methods but improves performance; the second relies on programming using types explicitly.

Comment: Actually, I am suggesting, the existence of the term "compile-time polymorphism" may be a counter-example to your answer. Your description of *polymorphism* seems more about *dynamic dispatch*, rather than the term "polymorphism" which has  a broader meaning.

Comment: @NickyC: Sure, that's why I gave a nod to it in my answer by saying "Often not known at compile time."  But the OP is a novice, so this discussion is basically off-topic for the given question.

Comment: I would say the "often"-clause looks like an underemphasis to some readers. And I would question the off-topic-ness due to the clause *whether overloading is or is not a form of polymorphism* in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Overloading is a subset of Polymorphism. Polymorphism is of two types: On run-time and compile-time. Overloading belongs to the latter one (*there are some other facets of compile-time/static polymorphism as well like **templates**, **function pointers***)

Usually authors refer Polymorphism to the one done on the Run-time (*unless specified*) and if you are talking about that Polymorphism, then clearly *that* one is done on runtime (*John's answer already drew the basic differences w.r.t **inheritance/virtual function** in his answer there*) and overloading is done on compile time when your function parameters determine which overload to be called.

**Overloading - Static Polymorphism** *(Demonstration)*

Following screenshot can demonstrate how function overloading is static (*resolved before run time*)

[image]

**P.S**

In case, you would like to see, this is a related question about [overloading and virtual functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122037/overloaded-virtual-function-in-virtual-inheritance)

Comment: C++ also has "static polymorphism" which is not overloading.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I meant its one type of static polymorphism. But thanks for drawing attention there. I have updated it

Comment: I don't think all function overloading is a type of dynamic polymorphism. A compiler must resolve non-virtual function overloads at compile time.

Comment: @TrevorHickey I think you have misread my comment. I mean overloading is one of different types of **static** polymorphism (_templates, function pointers being others one_) I have added screenshot in answer to further elaborate it